# Linux socket released too slowly when program killed

Tags: c, linux, sockets

**EDIT:  tl;dr:**

Don't open sockets with the wrong options, it's unlikely to work!

**Original Question:**

I'm working with a program which doesn't have a clean shutdown mechanism, it just relies on being killed to terminate it.

It opens a socket as follows:

```
(void) setsockopt(h, SOL_SOCKET, (SO_KEEPALIVE | SO_REUSEADDR), (int *) & optval, sizeof( optval ));
```

The re-use address option does seem to work, in that **eventually** the socket is released after the program dies.  Eventually being anything from a couple of seconds up to maybe a minute.

This is quite tedious as I need to restart this program regularly.  Making the program teminate properly would be a very big job, but I'm wondering if there's anything more local I can do to release the socket earlier?

Comment: You could just add a signal handler for `SIGTERM` and `SIGINT` signals (for example) that calls `shutdown()` and `close()` on the socket (which causes it to be released immediately) and terminates using `_exit()` or `abort()`.

Comment: I agree this is a good idea, and hopefully one day we'll fix the whole project to shutdown processes properly.  There's a whole host of infrastructure which will need to be updated to support this, so it's not a question of "just" adding it, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, if you do not currently catch `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`, then adding a signal handler that calls `close()` on the socket descriptor, then `sigaction()` to restore the default handler for itself, and finally `kill()` to reraise the signal, really is enough. The only difference to being killed by that signal (as happens by default) is that the socket gets closed first. If you want, I can show a minimal example program for that. (As to your original question, I agree with Maxim Yegorushkin's answer, so the example would be just an aside.)

Comment: Okay, that does seem straightforward.  I'm not a Linux expert, but now I've looked up SIGINT and SIGTERM, I can see this is practical without redesigning the whole project.  So thanks for educating me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Socket options are not bits and hence can not be or'ed like `SO_KEEPALIVE | SO_REUSEADDR`. To be pedantic, `SO_KEEPALIVE | SO_REUSEADDR` yields another socket option `SO_NO_CHECK`.

You don't notice this mistake because you don't check the return value of `setsockopt`. Now you know why ignoring return values is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, what @Maxim said. And once you fix your setsockopt calls and get SO_REUSEADDR properly set, I believe you'll see the behavior you want, and not have to wait on the socket in TIME_WAIT status to clear.